# Robot.libdoc is calling __init__ and failing

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using robot.libdoc to generate automatic documentation for Robot Framework, Python and Java libraries. Unfortunately in some Python libraries I have code such as:

```
def __init__(self):
    try:
        self.HADOOP_HOME = os.environ["HADOOP_HOME"]
    except KeyError as k:
        self.print_to_log("HADOOP_HOME isn't defined")
        raise k
```

Since robot.libdoc is calling `__init__`, an error is raised and the documentation file is not created. Is there a way to skip the error? I found it for run but not for libdoc.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to use lazy initialization. Remove any logic from the `__init__` method, and put it in `_init`, which will be called later by each of the keywords defined in your library. Example below.

```
def __init__(self):
   self._ready = False

def _init(self):
   if self._ready:
      return
   ''' your initialization logic goes here '''
   self._ready = True

@keyword
def my_keyword(self, param1, param2):
   self._init()
   ''' ... '''
```